# JavaFX - error using the FXML load() function

Tags: javafx, fxml

I am doing my first project using JavaFX and came across an error. After some hunting using prints and splitting the first line of the method below into smaller statements, I found that the error was caused by the load() method.

```
public Scene generateTodayGUI() throws Exception
{
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../fxml/TodayScene.fxml"));

    todayScene = new Scene(root, 450, 600);

    return todayScene;
}
```

I tried printing information about the exception and it gave me the location of wherever the error occurred. It is located at the 9th line of the FXML file that the method above is supposed to be loading. Below is the full line of code that generates the error.

```
<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="450.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="gui.TodayGUI">
```

I have verified that the controller class is stated correctly and as I was extensively searching for a solution to my problem, found some people had issues with the "xmlns", thus my guess would be that that is the issue here as well. And again, after hours of head scratching, none of the solutions that worked for others worked for me and here I am asking StackOverflow for help.

Thank you in advace!

PS: I am using IntelliJ IDEA

Edit: The exception is of type javafx.fxml.LoadException, the error message says nothing. And here is the stack trace:

```
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2625)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(FXMLLoader.java:105)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:941)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:980)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:227)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:752)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2722)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2552)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2466)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3253)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3210)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3179)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3152)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3129)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3122)
        at gui.TodayGUI.generateTodayGUI(TodayGUI.java:44)
        at gui.MainGUI.initSubMenus(MainGUI.java:84)
        at gui.MainGUI.<init>(MainGUI.java:47)
        at core.Main.start(Main.java:38)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:919)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$11(PlatformImpl.java:449)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$9(PlatformImpl.java:418)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:417)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:175)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: gui.TodayGUI 
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:547) 
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:936) 
        ... 25 more 
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: gui.TodayGUI.() 
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3302) 
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:532)
        ... 26 more
```

Edit 2: Here is the TodayGUI class. I am not including the imports due to knowing they are not causing this error.

```
package gui;
```

Here is the class declaration

```
public class TodayGUI implements Initializable
```

The attributes

```
public Stage window;
public Day day;
public Boolean isSaved;
public ChoiceBox<String> choiceBox;
public TableView<Meal> meals;
public TableColumn<Meal, String> mealDescriptionColumn, mealTypeColumn;
public ListView<String> exercisesList;
public TextField mealDescription, exerciseDescription, sleepHours, sleepMins;
public Scene mainScene;
public Scene todayScene;
public LinkedList<Meal> food;
public LinkedList<Meal> exercises;
public int hoursSleep, minutesSleep;
```

And the constructor

```
public TodayGUI(Stage newStage, Day newDay, Scene newMainScene)
{
    this.day = newDay;
    this.window = newStage;
    this.mainScene = newMainScene;
}
```

I'd also like to thank everyone who replied so far.

Comment: +1 for working on your problem. Still, your question can be improved with full exceptions details (type, message, stack trace) and [an executable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Since you're already managed to simplify your code, it shouldn't be hard to condense it into a short program that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: @defaultlocale thank you for replying! I have edited the post with the exception information you requested.

Comment: Please post your `gui.TodayGUI` class in full. The last `Caused by:` is a `NoSuchMethodException: gui.Today.<init>()` which leads me to believe `TodayGUI` doesn't have a _no-argument constructor_.

Comment: Also, the stack trace shows you are creating an instance of `TodayGUI` and then calling `generateTodayGUI()` which loads an FXML file which specifies an `fx:controller` attribute pointing to `TodayGUI`. This means a _new_ instance of `TodayGUI` is instantiated by the `FXMLLoader` (which fails, currently) and _that_ instance would be used as the controller; not the instance you already created.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @Slaw indeed it does not. But I do not use an empty constructor on any other part of the code, so I am guessing there is another reason why TodayGUI should not take any arguments?

Comment: You specified an `fx:controller` attribute. Absent a custom `controllerFactory` the `FXMLLoader` will attempt to instantiate the controller using the no-arg constructor via reflection. If there isn't a no-arg constructor then a `NoSuchMethodException` is thrown.

Comment: @Slaw apologies for a much late response and thank you for the help provided; much appreciated.

After a whole lot of experimenting, it all came down to the Scene and Stage objects not being static, which caused a number of NullPointerExceptions. Would you like to add an answer so that I can mark it as solved?